# callback on svn commit

Tags: svn

When i commit my source code(from my Netbeans IDE 6.7.1/6.9.1/) all the modified files are committed to the SVN repository but i dint get call back after successful commit..

Like "Committed Revision 5212"

Even same problem when i commit from Tortoise SVN Subversion:1.6.9

Details below:
SVN Server: SVN 1.6.12 installed on remote machine

More than 50% of people are facing this problem in our company..

Please help me in this regard as it is major problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it commit even when you get no Committed Revision xx?

Comment: Do the people who do not experience this problem have the same configuration (client versions, etc.) as those who do? If not, what are the differences?

Comment: When 2 or 3 modified files are committed at once, it shows callback properly, the problem is when it comes to committing project as a whole which contains 5+ modified files.

Comment: Yes has the same configuration Netbeans IDE 6.9.1

Comment: Guys any clue on where the problem is